# Ubuntu 18.04 & 20.04 : Network Connection Activation Failed

Tags: 18.04, dual-boot, nvidia, 20.04, realtek-wireless

I was using Ubuntu 18.04 (dual booted alongside Windows 10) when the problem started. I installed Nvidia Drivers (version 450) and it asked me to enroll a MOK key by rebooting so that my driver would work. I did the same and after the reboot, the driver was working fine, but I realized my wifi would not connect anymore. It didn't say 'Wifi Adapter not found', just wouldn't detect any wifi. I tried installing `bcmwl` and `dkms` from my live USB, but that didn't work either. However, **when I booted into Windows and then rebooted into Ubuntu, the wifi magically connected**. But the problem persisted: Whenever I rebooted from Ubuntu to Ubuntu or did a complete shutdown from Windows, the wifi wont connect. But it connects and works fines when I reboot from Windows to Ubuntu. The `lspci` output is:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (rev 07)

00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 08)

00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)

00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)

00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 21)

00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f1)

00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)

00:1c.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #7 (rev f1)

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point LPC Controller/eSPI Controller (rev 21)

00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)

00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)

00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)

01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP108M [GeForce MX150] (rev a1)

02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi 
adapter (rev ff)

03:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Sandisk Corp Device 5005 (rev 01)
```

So my wifi card is Realtek and requires the RTL8822BE driver is what I understood. I then tried a number of fixes such as:

- switching off secure boot, then removing and re-adding an adapter (bcmwl and RTL8821CE because the required driver isn't available for Linux anywhere)
- using `ndiswrapper` on correct downloaded driver for windows
- uninstalling the NVIDIA GPU drivers (including Noveau)

None of these worked. Soon the wifi stopped connecting even after rebooting from Windows into Ubuntu. Even the system settings stopped loading after a point and I decided to reinstall Ubuntu. By the way **the wifi works just fine on Windows**. Now, I re-installed Ubuntu 18.04 **thrice**. The first two times, secure boot was off. The last time I installed with Secure Boot on. This time, again, the installer asked me to enroll a MOK key after reboot to install third party drivers for graphics card and wifi. I completed this, but the problem persisted: the system (if not rebooting from Windows into Ubuntu) would connect to the wifi, and then disconnect in a minute and say 'Network Connection Activation Failed' and then never detect any wifi again. I **can connect to my phone's hotspot using bluetooth tethering**. But, additionally, my packages wont install or uninstall properly, and throw linking errors for Clion.
**I then removed my Ubuntu 18 and decided to install Ubuntu 20.04**. Same story: secure boot was on and installation went smoothly. However, the same problem still persists. I have seen some other questions that suggested that updates could cause this, but I don't really know how to investigate for that. What can I do?

Comment: The issue seems to be related to the ``rtw_pci`` driver failing to load on startup. Kernel updates might be a problem.